# ERROR: conditional rendering based on array state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

is running on condition else... please 
I believe I am doing the verification erroneously. I believe I am doing the verification erroneously

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { Text } from "@actualwave/react-native-kingnare-style";

const Demo = () => {
  let data = [];

  if (data.lenght === 0) {
    return <Text>null</Text>;
  } else {
    return <Text>not null</Text>;
  }
};

export default Demo;
```

Comment: (1) Please explain more clearly what the problem is. (2) Please format your code properly

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: `lenght` instead of `length`.

`data.lenght` is `undefined`, but you compare it strictly to `0`, which will result in `false`.

Comment: How do I compare in this case?

Comment: Fix the typo. Use `data.length` instead of `data.lenght`